# How to find orders from repeat/old customers using sql query?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am using mysql.

I have `orders` table with column `customer_id, order_id, order_date(datetime)` now I want to find all orders on Dec 20, 2013, which are from repeat customers( not new customer, i.e. customers has placed some order before as well) in a single query.

`Orders` table has other typical columns as well not mentioned here. Let me know I can provide more data.

UPDATE: Can we do it without subquery? If yes how? (Just curious)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select customer_id , order_id, order_date from orders where order_date between
'20/12/2013 00:00:00' and '20/12/2013 23:59:00' AND
customer_id IN (SELECT customer_id FROM orders where order_date < '20/12/2013')
```

Comment: You should really avoid the use of `BETWEEN` when [dealing with date/time/timestamp values](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common) (yes, I'm aware that MySQL doesn't have the exact same issues as SQL Server - it more has to do with consistency).  Among other things, `BETWEEN` should be avoided any time the value is a measurement (which logically have some amount of error), or are potentially "imprecise"; this essentially excludes everything but integer counts, which then shouldn't use it for consistency reasons.

Comment: if the question is for sql just change the query

Comment: Nice, Serves the purpose. But is there also a way to get results without subquery? Would that be faster? Any performance tip?

Comment: I don't think this query is correct. It assumes that repeat orders can only come from customers who ordered before Dec 20, 2013. I think this query would fail to pull same day repeat customers i.e. customer who order twice or more on the same day.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that order_id is the primary key in the table orders and customer_id is a foreign key, you can use the following query with self join to pull the list of all order_id corresponding to repeat customers:

```
select order_id, customer_id  
from orders a, orders b
where a.customer_id = b.customer_id
and order_date = '20131220'
```

Answer (score -1):

Now check this query

```
 SELECT * FROM `orders` WHERE DATE='20/12/2013' AND customer_id IN (SELECT customer_id FROM yearly_sales WHERE DATE < '20/12/2013' )
```

Comment: That doesn't answer his question at all.

Comment: Well this does not check if customer is old/new.